# How to assign category on multiple products?

Tags: category, products-management

I can assign multiple products into a category when I am creating a category,  but how can I assign a category to multiple products at once?

I have tried to check multiple products in `Manage Products` and then `Update attribues` but I cannot edit category from there. I have also tried `Manage Categories` too.

Comment: I did everything but i am not getting products under category, please help me.
thanking you in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- In your backend, go to Catalog -> Categories -> Manage Categories.
- Select the category you want to add products to.
- Click "Category Products" Tab
- Reset the Filter, select your products, Save Category

Comment: Please check : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109044/notice-array-to-string-conversion-on-admin-category-product-save/ .  I am doing same whatever you have mention in your answer

Comment: @zedBlackbeard This is for Magento 1, your questions is for Magento 2

Comment: I think the way `assing multiple products` in Magneto 2 is same as Magento 1.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to Erfan's answer:

If there had been no products assigned to category before, there would be no products at all listed under "Category Products" tab.

`Reset the Filter` - clicking it is a must even when you see blank list (no products assigned). It will then show all products in whole shop.

Answer (score 0):

An easier option would be - Mass Category Assignment, under manage categories.
Helps you allot products throught a CSV file.

Comment: Is that a part of core Magento 1.x, or maybe a 3rd party extension? I don't see that option in 1.9.3.1.

Comment: Yes that has got to be a third party extension.

Comment: your answer is wrong as it suggest to use a third party extension without even name it ...