# Notice: Array to string conversion on admin category products save

Tags: magento2, category-products

I want to `assign products` from admin `category module`. But I am facing following using on `category save`.

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/m202/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Image.php on line 51
#0 /var/www/html/m202/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Image.php(51): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Array to string...', '/var/www/html/b...', 51, Array)
```

[image]

Here is, what I am doing.

[image]

I am using `Magento 2.0.2`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check vendor\magento\framework\Data\Form\Element\Image.php There on line number 51 in to the if there shuld have to be data should be converted using (string) . If you can not find this line then add it

Comment: @AsishHira : What should be add on it `Image.php`

Comment: paste here the code of image.php line 51

Comment: Something changed the value of the image attribute to an array. This is most likely an issue with a third party extension. Closing as not reproducible.